# Break point issue

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, debugging

I am putting a break point in a winforms application inside a function like

```
public void FillOutListViewCtrl()
{
    // code to be debugged
}
```

I put a breakpoint here. After running the application I just want to know what exactly is going on inside of this function. Is there any way to go to this function directly? Do I need to attach to any process to achieve this?

Project uses a complex class hierarchy and I would like to know the best possible way to solve my problem. <strike>I don't know of any responsible action for going inside this function though this project is large with a large class hierarchy.</strike>

Comment: If I have all the source code of the project, I change function's name to find out when building/compiling, what code uses the function :)

Comment: this is not the one i actually need without pressing the action which i dont know though i need to move break point to these function so that i can understand the details

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything special. Just follow these steps:

1. set correct startup project within your solution
2. set breakpoint
3. hit <kbd>F5</kbd>
4. run your application to the point where you know your function should be called
5. debug

If you can't hit <kbd>F5</kbd> (for whatever reason)

1. run your application
2. set breakpoint
3. attach to your application's process (you'll see it in the process list)
4. GOTO step #4 above

That's it.
*(if that's what you were asking)*

Comment: this is not the one i actually need without pressing the action which i dont know though i need to move break point to these function so that i can understand the details

Answer (score 1):

If you run the program with the debugger of visual studio attached (just press F5) and you have a breakpoint in the method, than the program execution should stop whan the method is being called and you should be able to step through the method.

So, no, nothing special needed.

Comment: this is not the one i actually need without pressing the action which i dont know though i need to move break point to these function so that i can understand the details

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't get what you want to do. Move the breakpoint? Just open the file in Visual Studio, scroll to the method and set a breakpoint at it's first line...

Comment: this is not what i interested to know,,finally i found the responsible action to trigger in to the reponsible method where breakpoint is inserted

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint at the first line of the method.
Run yur application.
 When the method is called the execution stops at your breakpoint.
 Now step through the method by `F10` key .
 you can rightclick on some variables and **quickwatch** variables,
skip execution to different line by rightclick and **set next statement** to the line. 
Again F5 to execute the rest.

If it helps please mark as answer.